# RewriteEngine On not working but redirect working

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I want to redirect to some page and need to remove tailing slash at the end of the url.

`RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/?$ /product.html` //working nicely but after add below code stop redirecting all redirect matches

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

why its not working. in conf file added AllowOverwrite All

Comment: @ anubhava getting internal server error as expected.so my htaccess is enabled

Comment: Maybe `mod_rewrite` is not installed

Comment: @treyBake - they do with the `R=301` flag ;)

Comment: @CD001 the more ya know :p seems weird though, feel like I'd prefer to keep redirects to redirects and rewrites to rewrites :S but I imagine there are definite cases where to use rewrite with R flag

Comment: What are you actually trying to redirect? This works as I'd expect on my dev box, e.g. `http://127.0.0.1/does-not-exist/` redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/does-not-exist` which throws a 404 error; the requested file doesn't exist and, since there's no trailing slash now, the RewriteRule isn't triggered 2nd time around.

Comment: Can you comment `RewriteCond` line and retest.